# Nuxt3 dynamic images showing in dev env. not in build

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am using :src to render dynamic images. They are rendered in dev env. But do not appear after running yarn build.

```html
<img class="rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg" :src="person.imageUrl" alt=""/>
```

```json
"imageUrl": "/assets/images/team/Jamiepleasants.jpg"
```

Comment: Hi, sounds unfortunate. Would you mind giving more context? Some code snippets, any possible leads like any console errors, etc?

Comment: Using this to render the image
<img class="rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg" :src="person.imageUrl" alt=""/>
importing this data from json file 
"imageUrl": "/assets/images/team/Jamiepleasants.jpg",


this code renders the image in dev env. All the static images are being rendered after the build but the images with dynamic addresses stops rendering.

Comment: Comment section is not suitable for code. Please edit your question with proper indentation/highlighting please.

Comment: Please give a try to `:src="require(person.imageUrl)"`.

Comment: Tried using it but it gives an error that require is not defined.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're probably using Vite and need it's alternative.

Comment: Is there any way of solving this issue while using Vite ?

Comment: Check that one: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url `This pattern also supports dynamic URLs via template literals` etc...

Comment: @kissu thanks for your help. Went with nuxt-image module instead and it worked for me.

Comment: I've posted an answer so that we can have a definitive conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, OP solved the issue by using the image module of Nuxt: https://github.com/nuxt/image